# Regex for different prices formats

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a regex that mathes below prices, and then let me parse them into other format:

- before->after
- 2,232.99 -> 2232.99
- 8224.56 -> 8224.56
- 1125,59 -> 1125.59
- 345,99 -> 345.99
- 34.00 -> 34.00
- 431.333,0 -> 431333.00
- 34,99 -> 34,99
- 234.99 -> 234.99
- 42 -> 42.00

I've tried regex like that:

```
([0-9]?)[,.]?([0-9]{0,3})[,.]?([0-9]{0,2})
```

It matched,but then it is difficult to find in which group are penny values.What I want to make is to split this by the value of thousand, hundreds and pennies, and then just

```
return matcher.group(1) +matcher.group(2)
        + "." +matcher.group(3);
```

I am open to any other ideas how to parse it.

My code to test:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
       String[] testCases={"2,232.99", "8224.56", "1125,59", "345,99", "34.00", "431.333", "34,99", "234.99", "42"};
        for (int i=0;i<testCases.length;i++){
            System.out.println(parseLine(testCases[i]));
        }
    }


public static String parseLine(String string){
    System.out.println(string);
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(
                    "([0-9]{0,3})[,.]?([0-9]{0,3})[,.]?([0-9]{0,2})"
                    ).matcher(string);

    matcher.matches();
    return "group 1: "+matcher.group(1)
            + " group 2: " +matcher.group(2)
            + " group 3: " +matcher.group(3)
            ;

}
```

Comment: Is "431.333,0" - with only one decimal - a typo, or is this indeed a valid entry? Likewise, can entries have 3 or more decimals after the last `,` (or `.`, probably)? Are the decimal groupings in sets of 3 always correct? Either of these may make this impossible to parse correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best guess for a working solution:

1. Replace all , with .
2. Remove all but the last .
3. Format the number

This is very pragmatic, assuming prices can't have more than 2 decimals. Otherwise the problem does not have a solution: is undecidable.

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, you'll probably want to parse each pattern separately using alternation.

Try something like this:

```
([\d.]+)(?:[,](\d{1,2}(?![\d.,])))|([\d,]+)(?:[.](\d{1,2}(?![\d.,])))|(\d+)
```

It'll either match groups 1&2, 3&4, or 5.